# Group of people transported to a new world via spacecraft, face micro comets

Tags: story-identification

I can't remember much of the details, but I was reading this around elementary school time for me (1999-ish). It's about a group of people who get transported to a new world via a spacecraft, and they run into issues like micro comets.

I think the name starts with a "M".

Sorry I know it's not a lot to go off.

Comment: How many books in the series? Can you remember anything about the characters (names, ages, genders)? Was there a hero? Was it a Young Adult fiction book series or something aimed at an older audience? Why were they going to a new world? Do you remember anything about the spacecraft? Were the micro-meteoroids a regular feature or just one incident?

Answer (score 2):

Could this be Farmer in the Sky by Heinlein?

The part about the micrometeor would match as would the group of colonists being transported to a new world.Though the reference to an M in the title would not. Perhaps you are remembering the M as the ship was named Mayflower (in obvious reference to the colonization from the early American history)

"The story is set in a future, overcrowded Earth, where food is carefully rationed. Teenager William (Bill) Lermer lives with his widower father, George. George decides to emigrate to the farming colony on Ganymede, one of Jupiter's moons. After marrying Molly Kenyon, George embarks with Bill and Molly's daughter Peggy on the 'torchship' ***Mayflower***. On the journey, **Bill saves his bunkmates from asphyxiation by improvising a patch when a meteor punctures their compartment.** During the trip all the children attend class; also, to combat the boredom of the long trip, the Boy Scouts among the passengers form troops."

[Wiki Farmer in the Sky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farmer_in_the_Sky)

Answer (score 2):

Could it be [Spaceship Medic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceship_Medic), a 1970 science fiction novel for young people by Harry Harrison.

A ship carrying passengers to Mars is hit by a meteor killing most of the crew and leaving a junior medical officer in charge. The meteor also infected the ship with a disease.